# How to find search the sequence of element from multiple arrays

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have huge array of list, each may have some duplicate sequence i need to find the sequence (more than 1 element repeating in different array)

In this below example array 1 and array 2 having sequence of elements  **010,002,007**, also array 2 and array3 having **011,345,547,800** as common.

```
array1: 090,010,002,007,310,104,048,610,720    
array2: 456,010,002,007,087,011,345,547,800    
array3: 004,089,870,011,345,547,800,001,002
```

What is the best way to do this, I know we can do this in plain C# but it requires lot of loops and programming. Is there any algorithm to identify the more then 1 elements sequentially common in any arrays>

Comment: u need to find all matching elements of the arrays ,right ?

Comment: What is your the output from your example?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should try and map your arrays as graphs
We will define the following class

```
    private class Transition
    {
        public int ArrayNum { get; set; }
        public int? NextNum { get; set; }
    }
```

Given our arrays

```
var arrays = new[]
{
      new[] {090, 010, 002, 007, 310, 104, 048, 610, 720},
      new[] {456, 010, 002, 007, 087, 011, 345, 547, 800},
      new[] {004, 089, 870, 011, 345, 547, 800, 001, 002}
};
```

We will map the transitions as following:

```
var transitions = new Dictionary<int, List<Transition>>();

for (var i = 0; i < arrays.Length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < arrays[i].Length; j++)
    {
        var num = arrays[i][j];
        var transition = new Transition { ArrayNum = i, NextNum = j < arrays[i].Length - 1 ? arrays[i][j + 1] : (int?)null };
        if (!transitions.ContainsKey(num))
        {
            transitions.Add(num, new List<Transition> {transition});
        }
        else
        {
            transitions[num].Add(transition);
        }

    }
}

transitions = transitions.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

After having the mapping we will go each array only once, finding it's relevant sequences:

```
private class Sequence
{
    public int FirstArray { get; set; }
    public int SecondArray { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Nums { get; set; }
}



var sequences = new List<Sequence>();
for (var i = 0; i < arrays.Length-1; i++)
{
    List<Sequence> relevantSequences = null;
    for (var j = 0; j < arrays[i].Length - 1; j++)
    {
        var num = arrays[i][j];
        var nextNum = arrays[i][j+1];
        var flows = transitions[num].Where(x => x.NextNum == nextNum && x.ArrayNum > i).ToList();
        if (!flows.Any())
        {
            if (relevantSequences != null)
            {
                sequences.AddRange(relevantSequences);
                relevantSequences = null;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (relevantSequences == null)
            {
                relevantSequences = flows.Select(x => new Sequence { FirstArray = i, SecondArray = x.ArrayNum, Nums = new List<int> {num, nextNum} }).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var flow in flows)
                {
                    var sequence = relevantSequences.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SecondArray == flow.ArrayNum);

                    if (sequence != null)
                    {
                        sequence.Nums.Add(nextNum);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        relevantSequences.Add(new Sequence { FirstArray = i, SecondArray = flow.ArrayNum, Nums = new List<int> { num, nextNum } });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    if (relevantSequences != null)
        sequences.AddRange(relevantSequences);
}
```

Hope you'll find it usefull.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, what you wish for is to know if 2+ sequence are duplicates (can be in different order) in all the arrays, for example:
array1: **000**, **110**
array2: 111, **011**, **000**
array3: **101**, **000**
The common sequence are:
**1)** 000
**2)** 110\011\101

For the easy/short solution, I used strings array instead of int:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arr1 = new[] { "000", "110" };
    var arr2 = new[] { "111", "011", "000" };
    var arr3 = new[] { "101", "000" };

    var result = IsAllHaveMoreThen1SequnceDuplicate(new List<string[]> {arr1, arr2, arr3});
}

private static bool IsAllHaveMoreThen1SequnceDuplicate(List<string[]> arrays)
{
    if (arrays == null || arrays.Count == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var firstArray = arrays[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < arrays.Count; i++)
    {
        var isHaveMoreThen1SequnceDuplicate = IsHaveMoreThen1SequnceDuplicate(firstArray, arrays[i]);
        if (!isHaveMoreThen1SequnceDuplicate)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static bool IsHaveMoreThen1SequnceDuplicate(string[] arr1, string[] arr2)
{
    var globalCounter = 0;
    foreach (var s1 in arr1)
    {
        foreach (var s2 in arr2)
        {
            var isSameSequence = IsSameSequence(s1, s2);
            if (isSameSequence)
            {
                globalCounter++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (globalCounter == 2)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static bool IsSameSequence(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1 == s2)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (s1.Length != s2.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }


    var flags = new int[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
    {
        var cInt = int.Parse(s1[i].ToString());
        flags[cInt]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s2.Length; i++)
    {
        var cInt = int.Parse(s2[i].ToString());
        flags[cInt]--;
    }

    return flags.All(f => f == 0);
}
```

Comment: @ Daniel Tshuva, The first one is correct in my scenario "000" is common in all the. but the second one as you mentioned 110,011 are not same. both are different ids. Actually all this ids are my unique identifier in the SQL table. So i want to see if the sequence of ids are coming again and again in the different array (each array is my separate end product, each product is made of collection of small parts. so i want to group the collection of parts into single group and refer the same in each product)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. I made an assumption that sequence is at lest two numbers. The main idea is that I create all possible sequences first and calculate their sums. Then I do fast filtering based on sums and if they are the same then I do more detailed check.

This code can be improved with usage of more appropriate data structures. Some lists can be replaced with dictionaries etc.

```
static int[][] arrays = new[]
{
    new[] {090, 010, 002, 007, 310, 104, 048, 610, 720},
    new[] {456, 010, 002, 007, 087, 011, 345, 547, 800},
    new[] {004, 089, 870, 011, 345, 547, 800, 001, 002}
};

static void Main()
{
    SequentedArray[] sequentedArrays = arrays.Select(array => new SequentedArray(array)).ToArray();

    foreach (var baseSequentedArray in sequentedArrays)
    {
        foreach (var comparisonSequentedArray in sequentedArrays)
        {
            if(baseSequentedArray == comparisonSequentedArray) continue;

            var sameSequences = baseSequentedArray.FindSameSequences(comparisonSequentedArray);
            foreach (var sameSequence in sameSequences)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", sameSequence.GetValues(baseSequentedArray.Array)));
            }
        }
    }
}

class SequentedArray
{
    public int[] Array { get; private set; }
    public List<Sequence> Sequences { get; private set; }

    public SequentedArray(int[] array)
    {
        Array = array;
        Sequences = new List<Sequence>();

        for (int endIndex = 1; endIndex < array.Length; endIndex++)
        {
            int sum = array[endIndex];
            for (int startIndex = endIndex - 1; startIndex >= 0; startIndex--)
            {
                sum += array[startIndex];
                Sequences.Add(new Sequence(startIndex, endIndex, sum));
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Sequence> FindSameSequences(SequentedArray comparison)
    {
        var sameSequences = new List<Sequence>();
        foreach (var sequence in Sequences)
        {
            foreach (var comparisonSequence in comparison.Sequences)
            {
                if (sequence.Sum == comparisonSequence.Sum &&
                    sequence.GetValues(Array).SequenceEqual(comparisonSequence.GetValues(comparison.Array)))
                {
                    var smallerSequences = sameSequences.Where(existing => sequence.Covers(existing)).ToList();
                    foreach (var smallerSequence in smallerSequences)
                    {
                        sameSequences.Remove(smallerSequence);
                    }
                    sameSequences.Add(sequence);
                }
            }
        }

        return sameSequences;
    }
}

class Sequence
{
    public int StartIndex { get; private set; }
    public int EndIndex { get; private set; }
    public int Sum { get; private set; }

    public Sequence(int startIndex, int endIndex, int sum)
    {
        StartIndex = startIndex;
        EndIndex = endIndex;
        Sum = sum;
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetValues(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = StartIndex; i <= EndIndex; i++)
        {
            yield return array[i];
        }
    }

    public bool Covers(Sequence comparison)
    {
        return StartIndex <= comparison.StartIndex && EndIndex >= comparison.EndIndex;
    }
}
```